# Website Planning Mock Up

Tags: project

I'm a beginner planning to develop a website on my own, and have all the ideas, details, and how each page interconnect with each other in my head. Now, I do not want to spend too much time on writing all these in a document since I am quite clear on how the site would work. The only exception is the ER diagram. What I want to do is write a detailed description on the functionality and process for each page, and also, write mock up codes to outline the functionality of the page.

Is there such tool to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My top vote would be "pencil and a notepad".

If you want to save it electronically, anything that can draw text boxes and lines would be adequate - MS Word, MS Powerpoint, Open Office, etc.

The best diagramming tool, bar none, would be Visio.  Visio might be overkill - but it would certainly give you everything you'd need or want.

PS:
You might also be interested in using Google Docs:

http://www.labnol.org/internet/office/create-flowcharts-in-google-docs/8051/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Mac, and you want to spend a little money, I recommend [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/).  You can use it for free for 14 days, but it's $100 USD after that. One of the things that makes OmniGraffle nice is the fact that users  have made lots of User Interface "stencils", which can be found at [Graffletopia](http://graffletopia.com/).